Is it possible to do motion blur for HDRI background?
I am doing space scene in Eevee and realized there`s no motion blur for the space itself (stars/nebulas, etc.) which is an environment map. Have not found anything about it. Is there something I could do? Activate some extra pass?

Use the Compositor to mix the scene (with transparent background) and the background?

that`s the viable workaround, thanks

and in the Compositor use the Filter > Blur > Directional Blur for the background
